# Strange nullPointerException error - database related

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

im learning how to work with sqlite database, and i tried to implement a highscore system in a game i made. reading rows works when i try to show the scores, but when i try to use the same idea to read values to compare them in the following method - it gives a null pointer exception error.

```
private void checkIfHighScore(int currentScore) {
    Cursor note;
    int rowScore;
    String moveName, moveScore, newName;

    for (long i=1;i<6;i++){
        note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(i);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        rowScore=Integer.parseInt(note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ScoresDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        if (currentScore<rowScore){
            for (long j=5;j>i;j--){
                note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(j-1);
                startManagingCursor(note);
                moveName=note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ScoresDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
                moveScore=note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ScoresDbAdapter.KEY_BODY));
                mDbHelper.updateNote(j, moveName, moveScore);
            }
            newName="a"; //for testing 
            mDbHelper.updateNote(i, newName, Integer.toString(currentScore));
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

i know the error is at the line after the for loop - but i have no idea what is causing it to fail. my database has 5 rows of data (verified). 
does anyone know what is causing my error? been banging my head against the wall for 2 hours on that. thanks!

Comment: How is `mDbHelper` declared and initialized?

Comment: It might be: `mDbHelper` is not initialized, or `mDbHelper.fetchNote(i)` returns null (we do not have the code for that), please add log cat and more code so that we can help

Comment: mDbHelper = new ScoresDbAdapter(this);
mDbHelper.open();

also keep in mind i use the same command (fetchNote) to read from the database in another method, so it is working well, mostlikely.

Comment: thanks, i found the solution - i declared the mDbHelper after i was calling for it in the other method, so it wasnt declared at time it was needed. silly me. thank you!

Comment: Great! As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the code you have you could do something like

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT MAX(COLUMN_NAME) FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst(){
   rowScore = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0);
   if(rowScore < currentScore){
       //you have a new high score
    }
}
```

This way you take advantage of the predefined functions that come with SQLite which are faster and save yourself some work.